# Gorm Many to one mapping with composite key

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to map a ManyToOne relationship with a composite key.

I'd like to be able to access the OnesolPeNames  domain object from RecoverySetup like so `recoverySetup.onesolPeNames.peNameU`

I've added the following code to my RecoverySetup mapping.

```
        oneSolution {
                column name: 'division' 
                column name: 'peid'
            };
```

**Table A**

```
class RecoverySetup implements Serializable {

    static constraints = {

    }

    static mapping = {
        table "recovery_setup"

        id composite: ["division", "peid", "orgkey"]

        columns{
            division column: 'division'
            peid column: 'peid'
            orgkey column: 'org_key'

            oneSolution {
                    column name: 'division' 
                    column name: 'peid'
                };
        }
    }

    String division
    String peid
    String orgkey
    OnesolPeNames oneSolution

}
```

**Table B**

```
class OnesolPeNames implements Serializable {

    static constraints = {

    }

    static mapping = {
        table "ONESOL_pe_names"

        id composite: ["division", "peid"]

        columns{
            division column: 'division', length: 8, sqlType: "char"
            peid column: 'pe_id', length: 12, sqlType: "char"
            peNameU column: 'pe_name_u', length: 50, sqlType: "char"
        }
    }

    static hasMany = [recoverySetups: RecoverySetup]

    String division
    String peid
    String peNameU

}
```

I get the following exception

> Caused by MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity:
>   org.hri.pisr.domain.RecoverySetup column: division (should be mapped
>   with insert="false" update="false")

I also found this SO post [One-to-Many With Composite Keys and Different Column Names in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487271/one-to-many-with-composite-keys-and-different-column-names-in-grails)

Comment: At risk of asking the obvious, has you tried to include "insert: false, update: false" in the mappings?

Comment: I've tried it like so oneSolution {
     column name: 'division', insert: false, update: false
     column name: 'peid', insert: false, update: false
    } with the same error

Comment: Nevermind! It was a dumb suggestion. Do you *need* to have a composite key? And you can make the relationship bidirectional with `static hasOne = [OnesolPeNames: 'oneSolution']`

Comment: Unfortunately this is a legacy database and I need to pull back a OnesolPeNames record with the recovery setup. So no way to do it without the composite key.

Comment: hasOne gives me the following error org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: onesol_pe_names_division in TEST_pi_salary_recovery.dbo.recovery_setup

Comment: Yeah, it's because it can't update the database. I wasn't aware it was a legacy DB. Grails and GORM tends to work well when you are implementing a DB from scratch. Okay, we can move this to chat!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82018/discussion-between-christopher-and-code-junkie).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Foreign key (FK\_ must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167194/foreign-key-fk-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-the-referenced-primary-key)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by GUL [Foreign key (FK_ must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167194/foreign-key-fk-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-the-referenced-primary-key/31167953#31167953)

class RecoverySetup implements Serializable {

```
static mapping = {
    table "recovery_setup"
    id composite: ["division", "peid", "orgkey"]
    columns {
        orgkey column: 'org_key', length: 8, sqlType: "char"

        oneSolName {
            column name: 'division'
            column name: 'peid'
        }
    }
    oneSolName updateable: false, insertable: false
}

static belongsTo = [oneSolName: OnesolPeNames]
...
```

}