# Foreign key (FK_ must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm working with a legacy database where Table A consist of 3 composite keys and Table B consist of 2 composite keys which are the same as two of the composite keys from Table A

**OnesolPeNames**

```
class OnesolPeNames implements Serializable {

    static mapping = {
        table "ONESOL_pe_names"

        id composite: ["division", "peid"]

        columns{
            division column: 'division', length: 8, sqlType: "char"
            peid column: 'pe_id', length: 12, sqlType: "char"
            peNameU column: 'pe_name_u', length: 50, sqlType: "char"
        }
    }

    static hasMany = [ recoverySetups : RecoverySetup]

    ....
```

**RecoverySetup**

```
class RecoverySetup implements Serializable {

    static mapping = {
        table "recovery_setup"

        id composite: ["division", "peid", "orgkey"]

        columns {
            division column: 'division', length: 10, sqlType: "char"
            peid column: 'peid', length: 12, sqlType: "char"
            orgkey column: 'org_key', length: 8, sqlType: "char"

            oneSolName column: ['division', 'peid']


        }
    }

    static belongsTo = [oneSolName: OnesolPeNames]

    ....
```

I'm trying to access OnesolPeNames like so.

recoverySetup.onesolPeNames.peNameU.

I'm getting the following error

> Caused by MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FK_ib9w9pn893cwi1dkk84qs31bx:recovery_setup [division,
>   peid,onesol_pe_names_division,onesol_pe_names_peid])) must have same
>   number of columns as the referenced primary key (ONESOL_pe_names
>   [division,pe_id])

I'm setting oneSolName column to `['division', 'peid']`, where is  `onesol_pe_names_division,onesol_pe_names_peid` coming from?

Could it be that my composite keys are a part of PK but also plays role as a FK which is known as "Derived Identities"?

Comment: I see that you're having problems to map your legacy database. I have a Grails Application that maps a legacy database where all tables have at least two composite keys. The difference is that I'm not doing the map using DomainClass, I'm using hbm.xml files (the Hibernate traditional way).

Comment: Same situation here, every one of my tables are two or more composite keys. Is there away to do this using a DomainClass? Management would prefer that approach if possible.

Comment: I don't remember the reason now, but I had problems to map my tables using DomainClasses. When I decided to do the mapping using hbm.xml files everything started to working fine. To generate the hbm.xml files I used a plugin for Eclipse called HibernateTools. This plugin connects to a legacy database (via JDBC) and automatically generates the hbm.xml and the .java related.

Comment: I'm thinking my issue might be Derived Identities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I resolved mapping table in this way:

```
class RecoverySetup implements Serializable {

    static mapping = {
        table "recovery_setup"
        id composite: ["division", "peid", "orgkey"]
        columns {
            orgkey column: 'org_key', length: 8, sqlType: "char"

            oneSolName {
                column name: 'division'
                column name: 'peid'
            }
        }
        oneSolName updateable: false, insertable: false
    }

    static belongsTo = [oneSolName: OnesolPeNames]
    ...
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, what does it mean when we say oneSolName isn't updatable or instertable? Does this mean I wouldn't be able to update any records in that table?

Comment: You can insert/update records in OnesolPeNames class as you want. But when you set the oneSolName value in class RecoverySetup you will do that setting/updating the primary key